# Javascript - send user location data to server at regular intervals (mulit-threading)

Tags: javascript, multithreading, asynchronous, geolocation

I have a javascript code that among other things has to periodically send user's geolocation data to the server.

If this had been C or Java, I would have just spawned another thread for this task, while the whole of other functionality takes place in a parallel thread.

But considering that Javascript does not support multi-threading how do I accomplish this task?

I found a few solutions pointing to [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Using_web_workers), but given that for IE only IE10+ supports it, I am looking for a more versatile solution.

Comment: following thread may be useful to you

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230226/how-to-send-geolocation-data-from-browser-to-server][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230226/how-to-send-geolocation-data-from-browser-to-server

Comment: My problem is not with obtaining the geolocation data, but to keep sending it at definite intervals. Because I have to repeatedly send it, I need to decouple this logic from the rest of the javascript code. I am looking for a solution for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is single-threaded. But you can use [setInterval](http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval) to "simulate" multi-threading.

```
function f() {
    send-geolocation
}
setInterval(f, 1000)
```

or

```
setInterval("send-geolocation()", 1000)
```

Comment: Just the solution I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` Functions which almost supported by all of the browsers.

by this you can call a recursive Function which does the task of sending Locations.

`$.ajax()` the jquery function can be used to communicate to the server asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sender = function(interval, url, collectGeoData) {
  this.interval = interval;
  this.url = url;

  if (typeof collectGeoData == 'function' ) {
        this.collectGeoData = collectGeoData;
  }
  else return null;

  setInterval(send, this.interval);
}

sender.prototype.send = function() {
  var data = this.collectGeoData();
  $.post(this.url, data);
}

var thread = new sender('...',50000, function() { //collecting geo data })`enter code here`;
```